Keep/add URL referral params in wordpress with any action click
I'm having difficulties figuring out what filters or actions should I write when I want to keep any params ('?ref={username}') in my URLs when user is navigating through the site AND is redirected to another domain.
How do I always keep '?ref={username}' param with every action link user clicks.
I cannot use add_query_var() , because if this is added, then user is redirected to /blog page, which is set up in my link permastructure for blogs/single posts/post templates/search/categories/pagination pages.
I found the following code can be used to extract the values and include, but I don't know what hooks to use.
$referralValue = isset($_GET['ref']) ? $_GET['ref'] : $_GET['r'];
add_query_arg( 'ref', $referralValue, $custom_redirect_url );

Any suggestions, pointers would be appreciated, thanks.
What I tried:

Using bricks builder, so I tried a filter for add_filter( 'bricks/auth/custom_redirect_url',....) . But it states in documentation that it's tied with auth flows.

Also wanted to add add_query_var(), but this one breaks my site, because user is redirected to /blog page, which is set up in my link permastructure for blogs/single posts/templates/search/categories/pagination pages.



"AND is redirected to another domain" - So you have example.com and someone is at example.com?ref=cheese. When they click any external link in body copy, footer, etc., such as to https://google.com, you want the query string appended to it, too?

Is there a specific reason you need this in the QS for every page? Can you just store it in session or a cookie the first time it happens?

No matter what, at a minimum you should probably register your query string variable(s) with WordPress: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/query_vars/

@ChrisHaas Yes , that's what I figured out also . No need to have it in QS for every page. I managed to find the solution with cookies and javascript event listeners. Adding the desired outcome as an answer. Thanks for also pointing this out!

It seems there’s a 2 part solution for this.
First, to detect any ref code in the URL and store the ref into cookies. Secondly, use javascript to add any link click event listener to include the ref.
Detect ref from URL and store it in cookies, I added both scripts to the body (footer) :
<script>
    function storeRefInCookie() {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const ref = urlParams ? (urlParams.get('ref') || urlParams.get('r')) : null;    
        if (ref) {
            const maxAge = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2; // 2 days
            const cookieValue = ref + '; path=/;' + 'max-age=' + maxAge + ';' + 'SameSite=None; Secure;';
            
            document.cookie = 'ref=' + cookieValue
            document.cookie = 'referredByUser=' + cookieValue;
        }
    } 
    storeRefInCookie();   
</script>

Add event listener
<script>
// Function to get a cookie value
function getCookie(name) {
    var value = "; " + document.cookie;
    var parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

// Add event listener to all link buttons
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(function(link) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default action
        var href = this.getAttribute('href');
        var ref = getCookie('ref'); // Get 'ref' cookie value
        if (ref) {
            href += (href.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?') + 'ref=' + ref;
        }
        window.location.href = href; // Navigate to the new URL
    });
});
</script>

Also, if anyone is looking for what filters to use for WP user navigation to write some customizations, here's the list (I didn't need it):
- add_filter('the_permalink', 'add_cookie_value_to_permalink');
- add_filter('page_link', 'add_cookie_value_to_permalink');
- add_filter('post_link', 'add_cookie_value_to_permalink');
- add_filter('term_link', 'add_cookie_value_to_permalink');
- add_filter('tag_link', 'add_cookie_value_to_permalink');
- add_filter('category_link', 'add_cookie_value_to_permalink');

